# Non-error message from another script when importing library

Tags: python

I produced a very strange error today, using Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 system. I wrote a Python script, `C:\Users\$me\copy.py` looking something like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    out = subprocess.check_output("do_stuff.bat")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "Doing stuff failed."

do_stuff_did_something = out.find("String to be found in do_stuffs output.")
if do_stuff_did_something == -1:
    print "Do_stuff didn't do it."
else:
    print "Do_stuff did do it."
```

So far, so good, this works perfectly fine and does what it's supposed to do: run the batch file, look for a specific string in its output, and return a message according to whether it found the string or not.

Some time afterwards, I installed the OpenOPC library. At some point which I don't clearly remember, this started happening:

```
C:\Users\$me>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import OpenOPC
Do_stuff did do it.
>>>
```

This also happens if I run a `python script.py` including the OpenOPC import. It does not happen with any other libraries (that I tried). And it's not an error message since OpenOPC works perfectly fine. I'm just afraid that I somehow messed up something which might catch me later.

I couldn't find a clue in `OpenOPC.py` as to when this message might get printed.

The error persists after rebooting.

So what happened here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your script located and what is it called?

Comment: It was (originally) called `copy.py` and located in `C:\Users\$me` where `$me` represents my username on this machine. I forgot to mention that the error persists after a reboot.

Comment: Try `python -v` and look for your `copy.py`.

Comment: Closest I found was `# C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.pyc matches C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your script is getting imported before (or because Python thinks it is part of) the `OpenOPC` library. Is your script by chance called `OpenOPC.py` or similar, or does it reside in a [package/folder hierarchy](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#packages)?

Alternatively, where did you save your original script? Is it in the package/module hierarchy of OpenOPC? That might also trigger its load in some unusual cases.

Lastly: does the error behavior reoccur if your run your `python somescript.py` (where `somescript.py` is *not* the one containing the script content at the top of your question) from a new/different directory than the one you've been usually running it from?

All of those tweaks will try to isolate the problem away from the situation in which your script is getting interpreted as part of the OpenOPC module. That's an unusual situation to be in, but is possible; if the problematic behavior goes away due to any of those steps, move/rename your script.

Comment: Here is an indicator of what happens/happened when I import OpenOPC in another folder; the error message is quite helpful: `>>> import OpenOPC [...] import win32pdh, win32api,time, thread,copy [...]   File "copy.py", line 6, in <module> out = subprocess.check_output("do_stuff.bat")` So OpenOPC obviously replaced some original copy library with my own copy.py script

Comment: I had deleted the `copy.py` but a `copy.pyc` remained in the directory. The message no longer appears after deleting that file as well.